# How to Group Multiple Product Links in my-downloads.php for WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, download, woocommerce, grouping

The basic set-up for listing a purchased product's download links in the user account in WooCommerce is:

```
echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_available_download_link', '<a href="' . esc_url( $download['download_url'] ) . '">' . $download['download_name'] . '</a>', $download );
```

This ends up showing like this in the account:

[image]

Basically, it lists the products name, followed by the included link.  If you have ten links per product to download, then this list gets long..  Then, if you have multiple products purchased, each with ten links, it's just a long run on list.  What I'm looking for is a solution to make this list look like this...and notice now where Product 2 starts after Product 1.

[image]

I'm totally surprised this option isn't standard, but I can't find any solution. I've tried and tried...so much code that I don't even know where to start.

Anyone have any idea on this WooCommerce issue?

Comment: I've wondered about that, but I don't think that exists yet.

Comment: Yes, someone good make a lot of money creating a simple plug-in that does this...but simple php shoudl work as well!  Wish I knew it better.

Comment: Wow, first question I've ever posted on stack with no response.  :)

Comment: Not really surprising. This seems like a big project and no longer a simple "question". There are SO questions/answers related to [php zipping on the fly](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+zip+on+the+fly) which is where I'd start were I to tackle something like this.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone out there who's looking to group downloadable items return by `WC()->customer->get_downloadable_products()` function by product ID.

This following below snippet modify the return data for the function `WC()->customer->get_downloadable_products()` to group downloadable files by product ID.

```
/**
 * Group Downloadable products by product ID
 *
 * @param array $downloads
 * @return array
 */
function prefix_group_downloadable_products( array $downloads ) {
    $unique_downloads = [];

    foreach ( $downloads as $download ) {
        $list = [
            'download_url' => $download['download_url'],
            'file_name'    => $download['file']['name']
        ];

        if ( array_key_exists( $download['product_id'], $unique_downloads ) ) {
            $unique_downloads[ $download['product_id'] ]['list'][] = $list;
            continue;
        }

        $data = $download;
        $data['list'] = [ $list ];
        $unique_downloads[ $download['product_id'] ] = $data;
    }

    return $unique_downloads;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_customer_get_downloadable_products', 
'prefix_group_downloadable_products' );
```

Once the filter is in place, use the filter hook `woocommerce_account_downloads_column_download-file` to modify the layout to list downloadable files in ordered list.

```
/**
 * Show number list of downloadable files for group product
 *
 * @param array $download
 * @return void
 */
function prefix_downloads_column_download_file( array $download ) {
    $lists = $download['list'];

    if ( empty( $lists ) ) {
        _e( 'No Download Files', 'storefront' );
        return;
    }

    echo '<ol>';

    foreach ( $lists as $list ) {
        echo '<li>';
        echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $list['download_url'] ) . '" class="woocommerce-MyAccount-downloads-file">';
        echo esc_html( $list['file_name'] );
        echo '</a></li>';
    }

    echo '</ol>';
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_account_downloads_column_download-file', 'prefix_downloads_column_download_file' );
```

One thing to note here, that the data structure of original download files array is unchanged, we have just introduced a new key `list[]` which holds each downloadable file URL and name in the `list` key.